# How to override background Image of body in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery function `addbluebody()` which add **blue color** to the body,

and a function `hideCongratAndBlueBody()` which removes it.

`My problem` is that `i already had a fixed backgroundImage set for my body`, because of that the `blue color is not showing on calling addbluebody()`

`how to override the backgroundImage of body and make visible bluecolor and again show backgroundImage when hideCongratAndBlueBody() ia called`.

```js
function addBlueBody() {
            $('body').addClass('bodyblue');
        }
        
function hideCongratAndBlueBody() {
            timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
                $('body').removeClass('bodyblue');
            }, 4000);
        }
```

```css
.bodyblue {
            background: #3da1d1;
            color: #fff;
        }

body{
 background-image:url(nature image.jpg);
}
```

Comment: add `background-image: none;` to your bodyblue class

Comment: @scraaappy i want to regain backgroundImage on hideCongratAndBlueBody()

Comment: @obsidian-age yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to override it; `.bodyblue` has more **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** than body, and assuming your element is `<body class='bodyblue'>`, the jQuery will add the class and change the background automatically:

[image]

```js
function addBlueBody() {
  $('body').addClass('bodyblue');
}

function hideCongratAndBlueBody() {
  timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
    $('body').removeClass('bodyblue');
  }, 4000);
}
```

```css
.bodyblue {
  background: #3da1d1;
  color: #fff;
}

body {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='bodyblue'>
```

If you find that this doesn't work, either increase the specificity, or remove the background with `background-image: none;` on `.bodyblue`.